# Determining angle of line

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In Silverlight, is there a way to determine the angle of a Line object? If I have a Line with coordinates of `0,0 - 30,80`, is there a way to determine the angle, in degrees, that the line is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try finding the arc tangent using the `Math.Atan` function. You just need to find the atan of the (delta of) y-value over the (delta of) x-value.

The answer will be in radians and you will need to convert it to degrees (rads * (180f / Math.PI)).

An example of this would be something like:

```
double rads = Math.Atan((line.Y2 - line.Y1) / (line.X2 - line.X1));
double degrees = rads * (180f / Math.PI);
```

(Note: I've never used Silverlight and I'm just basing this off the docs, so this might be completely wrong... you can also use Math.Atan2(delta y, delta x) too...)